# Question in Lemma $6.8$ $(ii)$ of Thomas Hungerford

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

While self studying Structure of Modules from Algebra by Thomas Hungerford I have a question in proof of Lemma $6.8$ part (II)

> **Lemma** $6.8.$ Let $A$ be a module over a principal ideal domain $R$ such that $p^{n}A = 0$ and $p^{n-1}A \neq 0$ for some prime $p\in R$ and positive  integer $n$. Let $a$ be an element of $A$ of order $p^n$.
> $(i)$ If $A\neq Ra$, then there exists a nonzero $b\in A$ such that $Ra \cap Rb = 0$.
> $(ii)$ There is a submodule $C$ of $A$ such that $A = Ra\oplus C$.

[image]

> Question is in $10^\text{th}$ line of proof of $(ii)$

I am having problems in deriving underlined line in image: how to derive $ Ra\cap (Rd+C) =0 $ ?

Kindly guide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we have $z \in Ra \cap (Rd+C)$. Then we can write $z=xa=yd+c$ with $x,y \in R$, $c \in C$. Then, reducing in $A/C$, it follows that $[xa]=[yd] \in R(a+C) \cap R(d+C)=C$, so that $xa \in C$, ie $xa \in Ra \cap C=\{0\}$, thus $z=xa=0$.

Comment: can you please tell in 8 the line how did you deduced that$R(a+C) \cap R(d+C) = C $ ?

Comment: That’s stated in the original proof, on line 9.